# How is non-volume data for a Docker container stored?

Tags: docker

I understand Docker volumes and the way they refer to directories on the host. What about the rest of the filesystem within a container?

To think about it a different way: suppose you have a server with most of the storage on a remote drive, meaning reads and writes take longer than usual. If you don't mount any volumes, would it keep any/some/most/all of the container filesystem in RAM? Or does it write some amount of it to disk, meaning it would be just as slow as a volume in this case?

Comment: Suggested reading: Section ["Understand images, containers, and storage drivers"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/) from the documentation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Non-volume data is stored in a layered overlay filesystem (in most distributions, this will be either an [AUFS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/aufs-driver/) or [DeviceMapper](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/) filesystem). The principle is the same in both cases ([image source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/)):

[image]

As already mentioned in comments, I can recommend reading the section ["Understand images, containers and storage drivers"](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/imagesandcontainers/) from the official documentation. This answer is just a short summary.

Each Docker image consists of multiple layers of filesystem images. For example, an Apache+PHP image might consist of (1) a generic Ubuntu base layer, (2) an additional layer with the Apache HTTP server installed and (3) another layer on top with PHP-FPM and configuration files (just an example).

When you start a new container from an image, a new per-container layer is added to the existing image layers. This layer will contain all changes that is written within the container itself (to non-volume directories).

Regarding your specific questions:

> If you don't mount any volumes, would it keep any/some/most/all of the container filesystem in RAM?

Nope, there's nothing in RAM (besides the usual filesystem caches). It's all in the overlay filesystem, which are mounted using AUFS, DeviceMapper or another storage driver.

> Or does it write some amount of it to disk, meaning it would be just as slow as a volume in this case?

In general, filesystem access in volumes is more performant than in the overlay filesystem. After all, a volume (at least, a regular host-based volume, letting aside volume drivers that add network storage volumes) is simply a bind mount to a regular directory in the host filesystem, bypassing the layer filesystem entirely. The performance of volumes in comparison to layer filesystem is (among other topics) investigated in [this paper](http://domino.research.ibm.com/library/cyberdig.nsf/papers/0929052195DD819C85257D2300681E7B/$File/rc25482.pdf):

> **AUFS introduces significant overhead** which is not surprising since I/O is going through several layers, [...]. Applications that are filesystem or disk intensive should bypass AUFS by using volumes. [...] Although containers themselves have almost no overhead, Docker is not without performance gotchas. **Docker volumes have noticeably better performance** than files stored in AUFS.